# PHP regular expression preg_replace

Tags: php, css, preg-replace, expression

I have some text with css style (taken from database, so when I use echo, css show up) and I want to use preg_replace to replace that css (for example with space). I tried to do something like that:

```
$some = "<style[\d\D]*>[\d\D]*?</style>" ;
$text = $result['text'];
$a =   preg_replace($some, " " ,$text);
```

...but its not working:  Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '['

Any idea how to fix that?

Thx for help and let me know if u need more info.

Comment: Try `/<style[^>]*>[^<]*<\/style>/i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your regex in delimeters. A slash is often used:

```
/regex/flags
```

In your case:

```
"/<style[\d\D]*>[\d\D]*?<\/style>/"
```

Comment: When dealing with HTML (!), it's often better to pick a different delimiter to avoid having to escape all those slashes.